How to Prepare Vanadium (Na3VO4) solutions buffered at pH = 7.5?
"I need to conduct adsorption studies on Vanadium using various substances like biochars and nanooxides. To prepare Vanadium solutions up to 320 ppm with a pH buffered at 7.5 using PIPES buffer, how should I proceed? Yesterday, I used 10 mM PIPES and adjusted pH to 7.5-7.55 for concentrations up to 40 ppm. However, at 80 ppm, pH rose to 11. Adding a few microliters of 1N HNO3 turned the solution yellow, possibly due to deca vanadic acid formation. We have limited buffer and prefer to use orthovanadate only. Any suggestions?"
